# Javascript Menu : Click on to extend & Click off to shorten

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I created a menu for a web project, but I have a problem with the javascript side. I would like to extend the div container if it's clicked. And vice versa, I would like to shorten it if I click everywhere except on it. Actually, the program is able to shorten and extend the div menu but I can't manage the events :

- if div is small -> extend it by clicking on it
- if div is big -> shorten it by clicking everywhere except on it

There is my program :

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.wrapper')
    const offClick = () => {
        menu.classList.toggle('active')
        document.removeEventListener('click', offClick)
    }
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        menu.classList.toggle('.active')
        if (menu.classList.contains('.active')){
            document.addEventListener('click', offClick)
        }
    }
menu.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 body{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   min-height: 100vh;
   background-color: #10131c;

 }

 .wrapper{
   position: absolute;
   width: 105px;
   height: 105px;
   background-color: #212532;
   border-radius: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   transition: 0.5s;
   transition-delay: 0.8s;

 }

 .wrapper.active{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
 }

 .wrapper span{
   position: absolute;
   width: 10.5px;
   height: 10.5px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 50%;
   transform: translate(calc(18px * var(--x)), calc(18px * var(--y)));
   transition: transform 0.5s, width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
   background-color: 0.5s;
   transition-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
 }

 .wrapper.active span{
  width: 67.5px;
  height: 67.5px;
  background-color: #333849;
  transform: translate(calc(90px * var(--x)), calc(90px * var(--y)))

 }

 .wrapper span ion-icon{
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 0em
}

.wrapper.active span ion-icon{
  font-size: 2.025em;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper.active span:hover ion-icon{
  color: #d33d32;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px #d33d32) 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebSite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span style = "--i:0;--x:-1;--y:0;"><ion-icon name="code-outline"></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:1;--x:1;--y:0;"><ion-icon name="moon-outline"></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:2;--x:0;--y:-1;"><ion-icon name="bulb-outline"></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:3;--x:0;--y:1;"><ion-icon name="chatbubbles-outline"></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:4;--x:1;--y:1;"><ion-icon name="duplicate-outline"></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:5;--x:-1;--y:-1;"><ion-icon name="duplicate-outline"></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:6;--x:0;--y:0;"><ion-icon name="ribbon-outline"></ion-icon></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:7;--x:-1;--y:1;"><ion-icon name="rocket-outline"></ion-icon></span>
        <span style = "--i:8;--x:1;--y:-1;"><ion-icon name="stats-chart-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    </div>
    
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks really nice :)

As far as the javascript code you could keep it simple by adding the event listener on the whole body and checking the target of your click event has a parent with a 'wrapper' class, by using the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.

```
document.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
    if(event.target.closest(".wrapper")){
        menu.classList.add('active')
    }else{
        menu.classList.remove('active')
    }
})
```

Comment: First, I would like to thank you for your quick answer. Your code works as I wanted, so it helps me so much. But now, the problem is that the span items are able to shorten the menu if it's clicked. In fact, I would like to use them as links in order to redirect the user to other pages.  Do you have a solution ?

Comment: I modified the code accordingly. Glad to see you got an answer that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that amending event handlers within an event handler is normally a code smell. There is usually a much better way to do what you need to achieve.

In this case you need to attach each of your event handlers just the once. `handleClick()` should be attached to the `.wrapper` so that it expands when clicked, and `offClick()` should be attached to the `document` so that it contracts the `.wrapper`.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const offClick = () => menu.classList.remove('active');
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  menu.classList.add('active'); // or .toggle('active')
}

menu.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
document.addEventListener('click', offClick);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #10131c;
}

.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 105px;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #212532;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
}

.wrapper.active {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.wrapper span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10.5px;
  height: 10.5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(calc(18px * var(--x)), calc(18px * var(--y)));
  transition: transform 0.5s, width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
  background-color: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}

.wrapper.active span {
  width: 67.5px;
  height: 67.5px;
  background-color: #333849;
  transform: translate(calc(90px * var(--x)), calc(90px * var(--y)))
}

.wrapper span ion-icon {
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 0em
}

.wrapper.active span ion-icon {
  font-size: 2.025em;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper.active span:hover ion-icon {
  color: #d33d32;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px #d33d32)
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span style="--i:0;--x:-1;--y:0;"><ion-icon name="code-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:1;--x:1;--y:0;"><ion-icon name="moon-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:2;--x:0;--y:-1;"><ion-icon name="bulb-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:3;--x:0;--y:1;"><ion-icon name="chatbubbles-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:4;--x:1;--y:1;"><ion-icon name="duplicate-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:5;--x:-1;--y:-1;"><ion-icon name="duplicate-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:6;--x:0;--y:0;"><ion-icon name="ribbon-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:7;--x:-1;--y:1;"><ion-icon name="rocket-outline"></ion-icon></span>
    <span style="--i:8;--x:1;--y:-1;"><ion-icon name="stats-chart-outline"></ion-icon></span>
  </div>

  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I can see clearly now. This is very astute, thank you for your help !

Comment: No problem, glad to help